# reverse engineering image format

Tags: file-format

Can anyone help me with this? I think it's a targa image
[image]

Comment: Why do you think it's a targa format? Do you have the code that reads (or writes) such image files?

Comment: It's a texture from a ps2 game

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Targa file, then based on the hex dump you've given us, it doesn't contain any image data. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA):

[image: The TARGA header format]

They further say:

[image]

And in the hex dump you've provided, the third byte is a 00. This means that either 1) it's not a TARGA file, or 2) it's not a TARGA file that contains image data.